# Can't close sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to create a sidebar. Manage to make it open, but it doesn't close, and i have no idea why. What's the problem in the code?

Expected it to open in the first click on the menu, an close with the other, but it just stays open.

Menu is the icon i click to open and close the sidebar.

```
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

menu.addEventListener("click", sidebarWidth)

function sidebarWidth(){
    if(sidebar.style["width"] = "5vw"){
        sidebar.style["width"] = "15vw";
    } else {
        sidebar.style["width"] = "5vw"
    }
}
```

Comment: ```if(sidebar.style["width"] == "5vw"){``` (double equal sign)

Comment: Replace ```if(sidebar.style["width"] = "5vw"){``` with ```if(sidebar.style["width"] =="5vw"){``` or better use boolean value initially set to false (say ```let open = false;``` ) and take ``` open = !open ``` on each toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 or 3 equal signs in an `if` statement. With one equal sign, you are basically saying `if( set sidebar.style["width"] to "5vw" )`.

```
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

menu.addEventListener("click", sidebarWidth)

function sidebarWidth(){
    if(sidebar.style["width"] == "5vw"){
        sidebar.style["width"] = "15vw";
    } else {
        sidebar.style["width"] = "5vw"
    }
}
```

Learn more about `if` statements at:

- MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: My god, i know about that and didn't notice it kkkkkk. It works now, thanks a lot